# Math operations from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, math

I imported myList from a .txt file (I converted the numbers to integers)

```
from math import *
myList = [100, 'sin', 0, 1]
x = pi
```

How would I go about calling the sin function for my given value of x?

```
myList[1](pi)
```

I hoped this would simply return sin(pi), but it does not, because it is just the string 'sin(x)'

Comment: We're in `eval` land here, the question is *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: What are you reasons for doing this? There is probably a better solution to your original problem.

Comment: [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) has some tools that could help.

Comment: Define x first. Then define myList, but take out the quotation marks.

Comment: I want to make a function that will perform Riemann Integral with a finite number of intervals in a partition. The idea is that I will find a approximation to integral of sin(x) between x=0 and x=1. I will have 100 intervals in my partition.

Comment: One way to use sympy is described in http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/basic_operations.html#converting-strings-to-sympy-expressions

Comment: How would I go about removing the quotation marks in 'sin'

Comment: There are no quotation marks in that string, they are only added in the input or printed output to signal an object of type string. Thus you can not remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store functions as string literals, store the actual functions.

```
>>> from math import sin, exp, log
>>> funcs = [sin, exp, log]
>>> x = 0
>>> funcs[0](x)
0.0
>>> funcs[1](x)
1.0
>>> funcs[2](2.71)
0.9969486348916096
```

However, if you don't plan to do something more involved with that list of functions, you can just call them directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read the list from a text file, is there a way to read it such that the actual functions are put into the list?
The text file I made to be of this format:

    100
    sin(x) 0 1

Comment: @JackMalrock I'd circumvent this entirely by having the textfile be a Python module from which you can import a list of functions, i.e. `from mathtools import funclist`. If you don't want to do this, maybe SymPy.